# Oracle APEX username lowercased @logout

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, case-sensitive

Implemented a custom auth function in Oracle Apex. Usernames are email addresses where the local mailbox part (aaBB@company.com) is a mixture of upper and lower case letters.

During login, I can specify the username to not get uppercased with the following:
`p_uppercase_username => FALSE`

Question is, whenever I logout of the app, and I get redirected back to the login page, the original aaBB@company.com gets replaced by an all lowercase mail address. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

If you check login page, there's probably a Pre-Rendering process named "Get Username Cookie" which contains something like

```
:P101_USERNAME := apex_authentication.get_login_username_cookie;
```

This is [APEX_AUTHENTICATION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_authentication.htm#AEAPI29130) documentation. Have a look at `SEND_LOGIN_USERNAME_COOKIE` procedure. It is, I presume, used in yet another process on the same login page, named "Set Username Cookie" which does this:

```
apex_authentication.send_login_username_cookie (p_username => lower(:P101_USERNAME) );
```

I'd edit it and **remove LOWER** function call, i.e. use

```
apex_authentication.send_login_username_cookie (p_username => :P101_USERNAME);
```

What do you say? Any improvement?

Comment: Thank you for the swift response. Above changes works swell!

Comment: If this answers your question, don't forget to mark this response as the answer.